# Can I remove nested for loop from my batch?

Tags: apex, batch, class

Need help with below batch class. I need to update account lookup field in contact object (if NULL) using the id of the account lookup field in the associated Case object(associated with the corresponding account).

I used two for-loops. Can someone help me in executing the logic Using Map in the execute method?

```
global class BatchCase implements Database.Batchable<Sobject>{

    global Database.querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
       return Database.getQueryLocator( [Select ID,accountid,contactid,priority from Case]);   
     }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Case> scope){

           Set<id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
           for(Case cs:scope){
           accountids.add(cs.accountid);

           }

        List<Contact> ConsToUpdate = new List<Contact>();
        List<Account> AccLst = new List<Account>();

        List<Contact> ConLst= [select id,accountId from Contact where AccountId IN:accountids];
        for(Case c:scope){
            for (Contact c1:ConLst){
                c1.id=c.ContactId;
                if(c1.accountid == null)    
                c1.accountid=c.accountid;
                ConsToUpdate.add(c1);

                }

        }
        update ConsToUpdate;
        system.debug('CONTACT LIST TO BE--'+ConsToUpdate);
        }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, there are some problems in your code. Where does the variable `accAssign` come from? Why are you limiting to one record your query on the cases?

Comment: are you able to compile the batch?

Comment: Yes, But failing to update account field on contact.

Comment: Please refrain from using all caps, and try to come up with more informative titles.

Comment: Using a map, you should be able to do that.

Comment: As @MartinLezer pointed , Where does the variable accAssign come from

Comment: @Samir, refer updated code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understand well your code because I think there's a problem with this line:

```
c1.id=c.ContactId;
```

I suppose you want to check if `c1.id == c.ContactId`

Also, there's a big logic problem in your code. Your querying the contacts with an account id linked to some cases. Then you check if the accountid of theses contact is null. It can't be null.

Here's the solution:

```
    Set<id> contactsIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(Case cs:scope){
       contactsIds.add(cs.ContactId);
    }

    Map<Id, Contact> contactsById = new Map<Id, Contact>([select id,accountId from Contact where Id IN :contactsIds AND AccountId = null]);
    for(Case c:scope){
        Contact caseContact = contactsById.get(c.ContactId);
        caseContact.AccountId = c.AccountId;
        ConsToUpdate.add(caseContact);
     }
```

Comment: Should it have a containsKey check in map?

Comment: @RahulSharma I don't think so. Because I fill the Set with the Ids from the cases. Then I query the Contacts from the Set. So it should exists in the Map.

Comment: Thanks a ton,Martin and for all those who responded. Really appreciate all your kind help. Tks.